# Why does `sudo -i` but not `sudo` remove newline characters?

Tags: bash, command-line, sudo, quoting, newlines

What can explain the examples below and how do I fix this, preferably without heavy quoting acrobatics? I am using the `$n` to simulate multiple line command strings, just in case it distracts you from the real question.

```
~$ n=$'\n'; sudo -i echo "line1${n}line2${n}"
line1line2
~$
```

but

```
~$ n=$'\n'; sudo echo "line1${n}line2${n}"
line1
line2

~$
```

Comment: What is root’s shell?

Comment: They are both `bash`. Also, `diff -s <(sudo bash -c 'shopt') <(sudo -i bash -c 'shopt')` returns `Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical`. But, more importantly, are you actually implying you tested it on some box of yours and you couldn't replicate the (...) output I pasted above?

Comment: also interesting: `FOO=X$'\t'Y$'\n'Z; sudo -i echo "$FOO"` linebreak gets removed, but not the tab

Comment: Fair enough; I would just suggest a replacement of "endline" with "newline", as I think that's the more common term.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Disclaimer: this is my first rollback ever. This has nothing to do with `echo`. Actually I created this fake "`echo`-based" example to keep things simple. It's `sudo -i` that does this [and it does it] to any command. Test it with `bash -c`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, I agree to that bit. *Note: I resent my reply (almost with no modification), which explains why it's shown after JeffSchaller's answer.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running that `sudo -i echo $'line1\nline2'` under strace shows Bash gets started like this:

```
9183  execve("/bin/bash", ["-bash", "--login", "-c", "echo line1\\\nline2\\\n"], ...
```

Now, `strace` presents special characters with backslash-escapes when it displays the strings, so what Bash actually gets as the argument to `-c` is `echo line1[backslash][newline]line2[backslash][newline]` and for the shell, a backslash at the end of a line marks a continuation line and removes the backslash and the following newline.

Without `-i`, `sudo` runs `echo` directly, without going through the shell:

```
9189  execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "line1\nline2\n"], ...
```

Here, that's a literal newline going to `echo`, and `echo` duly prints that.

---

The idea here must be that `sudo` tries to add a layer of shell escaping to accommodate for the fact that `sh -c` takes a *single* string, while `sudo` itself takes the command as distinct arguments.

Compare the following cases:

`sudo` escapes the space (this is just the name of the command, no arguments!):

```
$ sudo -i 'echo foo'
-bash: echo foo: command not found
```

`sudo` escapes the backslash, so that this actually works (Bash's `echo` doesn't process the backslash):

```
$ sudo -i echo 'foo\bar'
foo\bar
```

Same with a tab:

```
$ sudo -i echo $'foo\tbar'
foo     bar
```

Here, there's no extra quoting on the backslash, so Bash removes it while processing the shell command line (`b` isn't a special character to the shell, and doesn't need quoting. This is basically the same as `bash -c 'echo foo"b"ar'`):

```
$ bash -c 'echo foo\bar'
foobar
```

The problem is just that you can't escape a newline with a backslash, and `sudo` doesn't seem to take that into account.

In any case, quoting issues like this probably turn quite a bit easier if you store the commands you want in a file, and run that as a script.

Comment: So do you think there is no workaround other than using (conventional) files? I would like to at least use something like `sudo -i <(echo "$command")`. Or some substitution cheats. Any idea?

Comment: I can't really say anything about other workarounds, I just said that using a file would probably not have that many quoting issues. Process substitution would be a good idea since it makes stuff look like files. Alas, it doesn't work at least on my system, I suppose `sudo` closes the file handle used by it. Of course you could use a temporary named pipe but that seems a bit complicated to do manually.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the structure of the command:

```
echo "echo \"line1${n}line2${n}\"" | sudo -i bash -s
```

This way `sudo` does not see the argument and thus cannot mess it up.