# Why do I need curly braces when using a variable in some versions of sudo -i?

Tags: bash, sudo, variable

Consider the following command:

```
sudo -i bash -c 'A=2; echo "|${A}|"; echo "|$A|";'
```

When I run this on Debian Linux with `bash 4.2.37` and `sudo 1.8.5p2` it prints:

```
|2|
|2|
```

But when I run it on MacOS High Sierra with `bash 3.2.57` and `sudo 1.8.17p1` it prints:

```
|2|
||
```

Why doesn't `$A` show without the curly braces?

This doesn't happen if the `-i` option is omitted -- both `2` are printed. And it doesn't happen if I just run `bash` without going through `sudo`.

Ran into this behavior in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51255260/1491895) to a SO question. The answerer there is running Linux with `bash 4.3.48` and `sudo 1.8.16` and getting the missing output. So it looks like it's related to the `sudo` version (or maybe something in `/etc/sudoers` that his Linux and my Mac have in common).

Comment: Symptom also manifests with `echo "|-$A-|"`. And the use case is repeatable on a Linux system with `sudo` 1.8.19p1 and `bash` 4.4.11(1).

Comment: For the -i invocation, strace gives `execve("/bin/bash", ["-bash", "--login", "-c", "bash -c A\\=2\\;\\ echo\\ \\\"\\|$\\{A\\}\\|\\\"\\;\\ echo\\ \\\"\\|$A\\|\\\"\\;"]`. After my eyes recover from this, I will try to parse it.

Comment: I suspect sudo isn't, but ought to be, adding a backslash or two in front of all the `$` chars.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Not just MacOS. It seems to be sudo version-specific, I've updated the title.

Comment: Also seen on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Sounds likely. The `-i` option apparently causes a wrapping `bash -c` invocation.

Comment: I'm sure I saw another question on one of the Stacks about this recently, and yes, I recall something about it parsing the string and trying to "do the right thing" with quotes. Can't find it though.

Comment: On debian jessie, I get a missing 2 on 2nd line. But is fine without `sudo`, or without `-i`.

Comment: I just removed the `|`s, it is not them.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Indeed, the original code that prompted this didn't have them, I added them just to make the output easier to see.

Comment: Known bug, fix uncertain. https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=765

Comment: See: [Why does `sudo -i` but not `sudo` remove newline characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447594/170373) and [Why does a 'sudo -i' login shell break a here-doc command string argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410531/170373)

Comment: @ilkkachu I noticed the newline issue as well, but it happened in the version that doesn't have the dollar sign problem, so didn't think they were aspects of the same problem.